# Removing blank pages from a newly generated pdf file with python

Tags: python, pdf, fpdf, pypdf

With the code below, I am trying to paste pictures out of a directory into a PDF file. The code is already working and generating my PDF almost as I wish.

The only problem that occurs is that it keeps adding blank pages between the pictures and I just don't know why.
If I execute the code, the PDF starts with a blank page, then picture 1, blank page, picture 2 and so on. So I end up with a 50 page PDF file for 25 pictures.

The pictures are inserted correctly though, without any white borders around them. They fit the page size perfectly.

```
from fpdf import FPDF
from PIL import Image

def CreateList(End):
    _list = []
    for i in range(1, End + 1):
        _list.append(i)        
    return(_list)    

def makePdf(pdfFileName, listPages, dir = ''):
    if (dir):
        dir += "\\"

    cover = Image.open(dir + str(listPages[0]) + ".jpg")
    width, height = cover.size[0], cover.size[1]

    pdf = FPDF(unit = "pt", format = [width, height])

    for page in listPages:
        pdf.set_margins(0,0,0)
        pdf.add_page()
        pdf.image(dir + str(page) + ".jpg")

    pdf.output(dir + pdfFileName + ".pdf", "F")

listPages = CreateList(26)
makePdf('file', listPages, 'dir')
```

How can I avoid the problem with the added blank pages?

Alternatively, is there a way to search for blank pages in my newly generated PDF file and delete them out of it?

Comment: The Documentation tells _**There is no page for the moment, so we have to add one with add_page.**_.

Comment: You should also check out img2pdf.py

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My initial guess would be that you need to disable set_auto_page_break:

```
fpdf.set_auto_page_break(0)
```

See docs here: https://github.com/reingart/pyfpdf/blob/master/docs/reference/set_auto_page_break.md

Comment: how to open existing PDF using this library? I was not able to find it in Documentation